# Serializing Date in Java

Tags: java, web-services, serialization, date

I'm passing around some objects through web service and some of them contain java.sql.Date. Because Date doesn't have empty constructor it doesn't want to get serialized.

First part of a question is easy: what is the best way to pass a date between client and service?

Second part is bit trickier: Once I decide how to pass dates around, I can obviously declare date transient and make some wrapper class to pass dates as String or whatever, but how to apply same solution as transparently as possible to several classes that include Date?

(I have a hunch that DynamicProxy thingy might be a solution, but reading documentation on Sun's site wasn't very helpful, so if it really is something in that direction, some clarification would be appreciated)

Edit: I asked wrong question, sorry (some misunderstanding between me and coworker what is actually a problem). Problem occurs because of deserializing. So once I have date in xml format it tries to deserialize itself as GregorianCalendar. Other part of a question still remains: What is the best way to receive something (long timestamp or GregorianCalendar) and convert it to sql date, without making 10 different wrappers for 10 different classes. I'm using a NetBeans for code and wsdl generation.

Answer (score 9):

## Joda-Time

The Date class has a clunky API. A better implementation is [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).

## ISO 8601

Joda-Time also allows you to convert your date in a [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard format (yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:SS.SSS). Using this standard when moving dates from server to its client has the advantage to include the full date in a readable format. When you use for example [JAXB](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/), the XML representation of a date is also this ISO standard. (see the XMLGregorianCalendar class)

Comment: Also note that the upcoming JSR 310 Date & Time API for Java 7 will be based on ISO8601 and concepts from Joda Time.  So this is a good future-looking direction.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know that myself. Finally a better Date implementation.

Comment: Nice article about the new API:
http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2008/09/18/jsr-310-new-java-date-time-api.html

Answer (score 6):

Serializing the long returned by Date.getTime() as previously suggested will work. You should however note that if your server is in another time zone than the client, the date you'll reconstruct on the other side will be different. If you want want to reconstruct exact same date object you also need to send your time zone (TimeZone.getID()) and use it to reconstruct the date on the other side.

Comment: if you serialize 2pm in Paris you'll obtain 8am if you deserialize the same stream on a machine configured for the  NYC time zone. If you want to schedule a meeting that's ok because you want everybody to attend at the same time. But if you need to display contractual information (ex: this option expires 2pm in Paris) then you need to send along the time zone in order for the NYC computer to figure out it's 2pm and not 8am, and btw, in Paris. Business cases exist for both situations, sending along the time zone is always safe, except if you have strict bandwidth constraints.

Answer (score 3):

To answer the first part of your question, I would suggest a string in iso 8601 format (this is a standard for encoding dates).

For the second part, I'm not sure why you would need a proxy class? Or why you would have to extend the date class to support this. eg. would not your web service know that a certain field is a date and do the conversion from date to string and back itself? I'd need a little more information.

Answer (score 2):

java.sql.Date extends java.util.Date

Just use getTime() to get the long value from it.  This can be serialized and a new java.sql.Date(long) or new java.util.Date(long) constructed from it at the other end.

Comment: Like entzik said above, this loses the timezone contained in the Date.

Answer (score 1):

I've looked into the implementation of java.sql.Date and as I see it java.sql.Date is Serializable as an extension of java.util.Date.

Answer (score 1):

one caveat with java.sql.Date that bit me recently is that it doesn't store the time portions (hours, minutes, seconds, etc) just the date portion.  if you want the full timestamp you have to use java.util.Date or java.sql.Timestamp

Answer (score 1):

I will expand on the [correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/114688/642706) by JeroenWyseur.

## ISO 8601

The [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard format is absolutely the best way to serialize a date-time value for data exchange. The format is unambiguous, intuitive to peoples across cultures, and increasingly common around the world. Easy to read for both humans and machines.

```
2015-01-16T20:15:43+02:00
2015-01-16T18:15:43Z
```

The first example has an offset of two hours ahead of UTC. The second example shows the common use of `Z` ("Zulu") to indicate UTC, short for `+00:00`.

## java.time

The java.util.Date & .Calendar classes bundled with Java are notoriously troublesome, confusing, and flawed. Avoid them. Instead use:

- java.time package, built into Java 8, inspired by Joda-Time, defined by JSR 310.

The *java.time* package supplants its predecessor, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library.

By default, both libraries use ISO 8601 for both parsing and generating String representations of date-time values.

Note that java.time extends the ISO 8601 format by appending the [proper name of the time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), such as `2007-12-03T10:15:30+01:00[Europe/Paris]`.

Search StackOverflow.com for many hundreds of Questions and Answers with much discussion and example code.

## Avoid Count-From-Epoch

Some of the other answers recommend using a number, a count from [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)). This approach is not practical. It is not self-evident. It is not human-readable, making debugging troublesome and frustrating.

Which number is it, whole seconds as commonly used in Unix, milliseconds used in java.util.Date & Joda-Time, microseconds commonly used in databases such as Postgres, or nanoseconds used in [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html)?

Which of the [couple dozen epochs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)#Notable_epoch_dates_in_computing), first moment of 1970 used in Unix, year 1 used in .Net & Go, "January 0, 1900" used in millions (billions?) of Excel & Lotus spreadsheets, or January 1, 2001 used by [Cocoa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocoa_(API))?

[image: diagram of different resolution of time tracking]

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20646345/642706) on a similar question for more discussion.

## `LocalDate`

> I'm passing around some objects through web service and some of them contain java.sql.Date

The replacement for the terrible `java.sql.Date` class is [`java.time.LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html).

Best to avoid the legacy class entirely, but you can convert back and forth by calling new methods added to the old class: `myJavaSqlDate.toLocalDate()`

### Serializing `LocalDate`

The `LocalDate` class implements [`Serializable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/Serializable.html). So you should have no problem with it automatically serializing, both marshaling and unmarshalling.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

First, if you are using web services, it means you are serializing to XML and not your regular Java serialization (but some other library for marshaling and unmarshaling). So the question is lacking some information.

Second, if you have control over your InputStream & OutputStream try extending ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream and override *replaceObject()* and *resolveObject()* and then you can implement serialization for java.sql.Date.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need default constructor (empty) in order to serialize/deserialize date (either java.sql.Date or java.util.Date). During deserialization constructor is not called but attributes of object set directly to values from serialized data and you can use the object as it is since it deserialized.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an encoder and decode to serialise and deserialise your objects.

Here is an example which serialises the SWT Rectangle class:

```
XMLEncoder encoder = new XMLEncoder(new FileOutputStream(file));
encoder.setPersistenceDelegate(
    Rectangle.class, 
    new DefaultPersistenceDelegate(new String[]{"x", "y", "width", "height"}));
encoder.writeObject(groups);
encoder.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

java.sql.Date already implements Serializable so no need to implement it :-)

As far as your main question is concerned, I'm deeply in love with JAXB as I can turn almost any XML into an object, so it might be worth your while to look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... Can't think of any reason why any serialized object-instance (serialized via the default java mechanism) should deserialize itself as an instance of another class as the class information should be an inherent part of the serialized data.

So it's either a problem of your (de-)serialization framework or the framework accepts any "date-like" object on the "sending end" (Calendar, java.util.Date etc. - an thus java.sql.Date too as it extends java.util.Date), "serializes" it to a String in some common date-format (so the type information is lost) and "deserializes" it back to a Calendar object on the receiving end.

So I think the simplest way to get to java.sql.Date is to do a

```
java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(calendar.getTimeInMillis);
```

where you need an java.sql.Date but get the GregorianCalendar back from the "deserialization".