# How to get the current month from Date

Tags: java, android

I need to convert a long value to any date. Next I want the month written out, converted as String. I wanna display the Month on a TextView.

I've tried:

```
Date dt = new Date();
Calendar cal= Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(dt);  //get current time

long dateAsLong = calendar.getTimeInMillis(); // get currentTime as long

CalendarView.setDate(dateAsLong); // give the view CalendarView the current date 


TextView tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewDate);
tv.setText(String.valueOf(dateAsLong)); // <-- but this is wrong
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Convert Long to Date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487460/java-convert-long-to-date)

Comment: Almost, but the main problem was to get the month name from the converted date. But thanks for your dedication!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

> convert a long value to … date … month written out

```
Instant.ofEpochMilli( myMillis )
       .atZone( ZoneId.of( "Pacfic/Auckland" ) ) 
       .getMonth()
       .getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.ITALY )  // Or Locale.US, Locale.UK, etc.
```

> ottobre

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

The other Answers use the troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

## java.time

Assuming your `long` value represents a count of milliseconds since the first moment of 1970 in UTC, use `Instant`.

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( myMillis ) ;
```

You want a month written out. Determining a month means determining a date. Determining a date requires a time zone. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ); 
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;  // Same moment in history, but adjusted into the wall-clock time of a particular region of people.
```

Now interrogate for the month. The java.time classes include a `Month` enum, to represent a month January-December.

```
Month m = zdt.getMonth() ;
```

The `Month` enum includes handy methods such as generating a String in an automatically localized format.

```
String output = m.getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.CANADA_FRENCH )  ;  // Or Locale.US, Locale.ITALY, etc.
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use following code:

```
    long longDate=12334;
    Date date=new Date(longDate);
    String month=new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM").format(date); //you can use month for display
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Date date = new Date();
    System.out.println(date.getTime());//Timestamp 
    long timestamp = date.getTime();
    date = new Date(timestamp);
    String month = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM").format(date);//Get month string
    System.out.println(month);
```

Answer (score 1):

First get the date from Long

```
long val = 1346524199000l;
Date date=new Date(val);
SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");
String month= df2.format(date);
```

Once you are having Month in form of string, convert the same into android textView by using the below code

```
textview.setText(month);
```