# JSON data is not being loaded back into ArrayList

Tags: java, android, json

I have successfully managed to save data entered by the user in my application into a JSON file in the application data folder.

Now, I am trying to load the data (if it exists) back into the application after the application has been destroyed.

This is the code I am using to save it into a JSON

This is my JSON saving and loading class:

```
public class CriminalIntentJSONSerializer {

private Context mContext;
private String mFilename;

public CriminalIntentJSONSerializer(Context c, String f) {
    this.mContext = c;
    this.mFilename = f;
}

public void saveCrimes(ArrayList<Crime> crimes) throws JSONException, IOException {
    // Build an array in JSON
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
    for (Crime c: crimes) {
        array.put(c.toJSON());
    }
    //Write the file to disk
    Writer writer = null;
    try {
        OutputStream out = mContext.openFileOutput(mFilename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        writer = new OutputStreamWriter(out);
        writer.write(array.toString());
    } finally {
        if (writer != null) {
            writer.close();
        }
    }
}

public ArrayList<Crime> loadCrimes() throws IOException, JSONException {
    ArrayList<Crime> crimes = new ArrayList<Crime>();
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        // open and read the file into a StringBuilder
        InputStream in = mContext.openFileInput(mFilename);
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        StringBuilder jsonString = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            // line breaks are omitted and irrelevant
            jsonString.append(line);
        }
        // parse the JSON using JSONTokener
        JSONArray array = (JSONArray) new JSONTokener(jsonString.toString()).nextValue();
        // build the array of crimes from JSONObjects
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            crimes.add(new Crime(array.getJSONObject(i)));
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // we will ignore this one, since it happens when we start fresh
    } finally {
        if (reader != null)
            reader.close();
    }
    return crimes;
}
}
```

It seems there is something wrong with `loadCrimes`. I've tried debugging it and it seems that it successfully finds the json file, I manage to see the json content in the debugger window:

[image]
[image]
[image]

It also saves the data into the `JSONArray` array but when it adds it to the `crimes` array it doesn't work. The size of the array stays at 0, hence no data is actually loading. It doesn't throw any error either.

This is my `Crime` class:

```
public class Crime {

private static final String JSON_ID = "id";
private static final String JSON_TITLE = "title";
private static final String JSON_SOLVED = "solved";
private static final String JSON_DATE = "date";


private UUID mID;
private String mTitle;
private Date mDate;
private boolean mSolved;

public Crime() {
    // Generate unique identifier
    this.mID = UUID.randomUUID();
    this.mDate = new Date();
}

public Crime(JSONObject json) throws JSONException {
    mID = UUID.fromString(json.getString(JSON_ID));
    if (json.has(JSON_TITLE)) {
        mTitle = json.getString(JSON_TITLE);
    }
    mSolved = json.getBoolean(JSON_SOLVED);
    mDate = new Date(json.getLong(JSON_DATE));
}

public String getmTitle() {
    return mTitle;
}

public void setmTitle(String mTitle) {
    this.mTitle = mTitle;
}

public UUID getmID() {
    return mID;
}

public Date getmDate() {
    return mDate;
}

public void setmDate(Date mDate) {
    this.mDate = mDate;
}

public boolean ismSolved() {
    return mSolved;
}

public void setmSolved(boolean mSolved) {
    this.mSolved = mSolved;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return mTitle;
}

public JSONObject toJSON() throws JSONException {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put(JSON_ID, getmID().toString());
    json.put(JSON_TITLE, getmTitle());
    json.put(JSON_SOLVED, ismSolved());
    json.put(JSON_DATE, getmDate());

    return json;
}
}
```

I'm running the app on ICS 4.4.2 API 19 using Genymotion Emulator. Coding on Android Studio 0.8.6.

Can anyone pinpoint what exactly I am doing wrong here?

EDIT. After restarting Android Studio, it is now showing me errors. This is the stacktrace. I've figured out it was a simple data type issue. Solved!:

```
08-20 15:34:13.019    2835-2835/? E/CrimeLab﹕ Error loading crimes:
org.json.JSONException: Value Wed Aug 20 15:26:15 GMT+00:00 2014 at date of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to long
        at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:100)
        at org.json.JSONObject.getLong(JSONObject.java:482)
        at com.apps.criminalintent.Crime.<init>(Crime.java:35)
        at com.apps.criminalintent.CriminalIntentJSONSerializer.loadCrimes(CriminalIntentJSONSerializer.java:68)
        at com.apps.criminalintent.CrimeLab.<init>(CrimeLab.java:28)
        at com.apps.criminalintent.CrimeLab.get(CrimeLab.java:61)
        at com.apps.criminalintent.CrimeListFragment.onCreate(CrimeListFragment.java:37)
        at android.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1678)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:859)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
        at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5240)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2168)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You can consider using [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to do the serialization/desiralization for you.

Comment: Thanks but I don't need a library at the moment, I'm learning how to do the basics first. I just want to figure out my problem at the moment.

Comment: can you check `array.length()` before `for` loop? is not `0`?

Comment: @orange ah ok. In that case, check if your Crime constructor is called and if the correct data is passed there.

Comment: @mmlooloo It is not 0.

Comment: @Joris Yep, it is called correctly and the data is being passed. I think it has to do with creating the object. Am I using the correct formats?

Comment: I've never used this tokener before, but usually to generate the JsonArray is as simple as `JsonArray array = new JsonArray(jsonString);` Also as debug mechanism you should put a breakpoint after your `while` look, copy the content (ctrl+c) of `line` and test it in this http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Comment: @orange the trace should tell you your problem : -) Seems like Addrallyn Wigolath has the right answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem come from your `Crime` constructor:

```
mDate = new Date(json.getLong(JSON_DATE));
```

A Date can't be parsed like a Long. I think you have a JSONException.

**Edit:** You can solve your problem by saving the time in milliseconds:

```
json.put(JSON_DATE, getmDate().getTime());
```

Comment: Thanks! I also found this answer useful too - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487460/java-convert-long-to-date