# How is a date value represented as a long integer translated into a meaningful date?

Tags: java

I want to know, how does this work?  When I pass a **long** integer as a date, how is that value transformed into a **Date**?

Ex:

```
    public Date converter(Long time){
     //what the magic?
    }
```

**This question is not new Date(long), I know this. But what do I want to know what calculations are used internally to produce the (human-meaningful) date value.**

Comment: `return new Date(time)` but don't take `Long` when you do make it work with `long`

Comment: @Jigar Joshi I know this. but I want to know how this work

Comment: Generally a `long` time is seconds or milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970, UTC.  It's a simple matter of arithmetic to convert that to a date.

Comment: He wants to know how it works. Like how it turns a long time into a date.

Comment: Have you considered looking at the source code?

Comment: as @HotLicks said and more [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Date.java#Date.%3Cinit%3E%28long%29)

Comment: @Hot Licks but what "matter of arithmetic" make this?

Comment: @Garis M Suero, Reimeus this question is diferent from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487460/java-convert-long-to-date

Comment: I put my answer into your question, since you were obviously misunderstood.

Comment: It is not now @GustavoRozolin... but it was at the beginning...

Comment: thanks @HotLicks for your answer. now I understand better how this work

Comment: Ok.  @GarisMSuero Can re-open this question now?

Comment: @HotLicks I think you can now put the answer as an answer, instead of as an edit ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Roughly speaking:

```
int days = longTimeInSeconds / (60 * 60 * 24);
int timeOfDay = longTimeInSeconds % (60 * 60 * 24);  // Leave converting this to hours/mins/secs to the student
int fourYearIntervals = days / (365 * 4 + 1);
int daysInInterval = days % (365 * 4 + 1);
int yearInInterval = daysInInterval / 365;
int daysInYear = daysInInterval % 365;  // For the student to convert to months/days
int year = fourYearIntervals * 4 + yearInInterval;
```

I think an additional fudge is required to account for the fact that 1970 was not a 4-year-interval boundary, but the above should be pretty close.

Key is understanding that every 4th year is a leap year, so the years are in 4-year intervals.  (The rules say that every 100th year is NOT a leap year, meaning that 2000 would not be one, but then a further rule says that every 400th year IS a leap year, so we're "safe" between 1901 and 2099.  Be thankful that you won't be around to see the disasters that occur due to the "Y2.1K bug".)

But keep in mind that many Time object classes store the time internally as a single number similar to the original `long` above, and only do the above conversions when asked to produce a character representation of the date, or to otherwise break it down into years/months/days.