# Java - long time to ISO_8601 string format

Tags: java, date, time, date-format, simpledateformat

I want to convert a date in long to a `ISO_8601` string.

ex:

```
2014-11-02T20:22:35.059823+01:00
```

My code

```
long timeInLong=System.currentTimeMillis();
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmZ");
String fmm = df.format(new java.util.Date(timeInLong));
System.out.println(fmm);
```

This will show in my console

```
2014-11-04T15:57+0200
```

I think that I want to get it

```
2014-11-04T15:57+02:00
```

How can I do that? (without string functions)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Convert Long to Date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487460/java-convert-long-to-date) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3914404/642706) and hundreds of other Questions and Answers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Using SimpleDateFormat on Java 7 or newer

Use `XXX` for the timezone in the format string instead of `Z`:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmXXX");
```

This works if you are using Java 7 or newer.

#### Java version 6 or older

For older versions of Java, you can use the class `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter`:

```
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

// ...
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(new java.util.Date(timeInLong));
System.out.println(DatatypeConverter.printDateTime(cal));
```

Note that this will add milliseconds, so the output will be for example `2014-11-04T15:49:35.913+01:00` instead of `2014-11-04T15:49:35+01:00` (but that shouldn't matter, as this is still valid ISO-8601 format).

#### Java version 8 or newer

If you are using Java 8, then it's preferrable to use the new `java.time` API instead of `java.util.Date`:

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(timeInLong),
                                            ZoneId.systemDefault());
System.out.println(zdt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME));
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the solution of my problem.

Comment: Do you know any way to do this on lower java versions ?

Comment: Added it to my answer above.