# java convert sql integer time into java.util.Date

Tags: java, postgresql, timestamp-with-timezone

In my postgreSQL I have the column created which stores the time when the row was created:

```
article_created TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT now();
```

How can I convert it to java.util.Date? The example of loaded value in Map():

```
article_created=1427233497
```

Comment: maybe calling the constructor?

Comment: Answer have found here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487460/java-convert-long-to-date