# integer to date java from Web Request

Tags: java, android, json

I'm working on a project where I need to pull person details from an endpoint. 
There is a field called 'birthday' that is a number that looks like something like this: 558289857
Any idea what form this is and how I can convert that to a date?

Comment: formate you getting is in long type see this ans : http://stackoverflow.com/a/7487489/4146722

Comment: post what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

```
long birthDateLong = Long.parseLong(inputMap.get("birthday")); //Assuming a string
Date birthDay = new Date(birthDateLong);
//This gives you, for your example (558289857), Wed Jan 07 13:04:49 SAST 1970. Perhaps only the date and month are meanto to be meaningful? Check your data.
```