# How to Convert Telegram Api Core date:int type into Java Date?

Tags: java, api, date, datetime, telegram

For some constructor or method parameter, there are date int type, for example:
https://core.telegram.org/constructor/updateShortMessage
updateShortMessage#d3f45784 id:int from_id:int message:string pts:int date:int seq:int = Updates;

There is date:int, a ten digit integer, the value for example: 1468782578 for today (Sunday July 17 2016), How to convert Telegram Api Core date:int type into Java Date? Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487460/java-convert-long-to-date

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for C# convertor and I found below for JAVA

```
public static DateTime JavaTimeStampToDateTime(double javaTimeStamp)
{
    // Java timestamp is millisecods past epoch
    System.DateTime dtDateTime = new DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0,0,System.DateTimeKind.Utc);
    dtDateTime = dtDateTime.AddSeconds(Math.Round(javaTimeStamp / 1000)).ToLocalTime();
    return dtDateTime;
}
```

reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/250400/1032109