# java Date object wrongly calculated

Tags: java, date

The following program produces incorrect output:

```
public class date
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Date d1 = new Date(1698526800000L);
    Date d2 = new Date(1698530400000L);
    Date d3 = new Date(1698534000000L);
    Date d4 = new Date(1698537600000L);
    System.out.println(d1);
    System.out.println(d2);
    System.out.println(d3);
    System.out.println(d4);
  }
}
```

result:

```
Sun Oct 29 00:00:00 IDT 2023
Sun Oct 29 01:00:00 IDT 2023
Sun Oct 29 01:00:00 IST 2023
Sun Oct 29 02:00:00 IST 2023
```

Why do d2 and d3 produce the same date although given different ms value?

EDIT:

i only wanted to know WHY this was happening, and i found out Daylight saving time was to blame on this one

Comment: Java != JavaScript, and this has nothing to do with the [tag:object] tag. Please choose only relevant tags.

Comment: The Timezone is different. So its not the same date

Comment: Clock change occurs at the end of October (in countries that do it).  Try it a day earlier or later and you won't see this "problem".

Comment: @SudiptaMondal: Well, the time zone is the same, but it's observing daylight saving time for the second line and standard time for the third line. Time zone != offset at a particular moment in time.

Comment: Suggestion: always start with the assumption that it's your understanding that is flawed, not the tools you're working with. Your assertions in the title and first sentence are incorrect.

Comment: @JonSkeet I agree that Time Zone != offset ofcourse. I just thought that IST was Indian standard time and not Israel standard time somehow, a wrong assumption on my part.

Comment: Your UTC output will be: Sat Oct 28 21:00:00 UTC 2023, Sat Oct 28 22:00:00 UTC 2023, Sat Oct 28 23:00:00 UTC 2023, Sun Oct 29 00:00:00 UTC 2023 so d2 and d3 are off by 4000 sec which is almost an hour. ignoring the ms part that is correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Convert Long to Date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487460/java-convert-long-to-date)

Comment: @i.net I don't think the OP is asking how to do anything.  They're just asking why they didn't get the results they expected.

Comment: I know that feeling of “this must be a bug in the system” all too well. Experience has taught me humility: it very rarely is when I think that way.

Comment: i simply wanted to know WHY that's happening, i didn't meant that the way this class is implemented is flawed, and i found out, it was because of Daylight saving time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although `Date` object has nothing to do with `TimeZone` (in Java, date just represents a point in time) when you call `toString()`, it uses platform/system's default timezones and shows date/time accordingly.

If you need to print all the dates with same time zone then you can set `default` timezone for your program (during app startup) prior to printing the dates, e.g.:

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date d1 = new Date(1698526800000L);
Date d2 = new Date(1698530400000L);
Date d3 = new Date(1698534000000L);
Date d4 = new Date(1698537600000L);
System.out.println(d1);
System.out.println(d2);
System.out.println(d3);
System.out.println(d4);
```

The above should print all the dates with `UTC` timezone.

Comment: thanks for the comment, i actually had the same problem with js, do you know how to cope with the same problem in js?