# Telegram bot Response: Date-Format

Tags: telegram-bot, date-format

I am trying to make my own bot right now. Now I am facing a small problem... When receiving messages via API the JSON looks like this:

```
   {
  "update_id": 297528782,
  "message": {
    "message_id": 2,
    "from": {
      "id": 148361373,
      "is_bot": false,
      "first_name": "yz",
      "username": "yz"
    },
    "chat": {
      "id": -403635451,
      "title": "bottest",
      "type": "group",
      "all_members_are_administrators": false
    },
    "date": 1583942557,
    "left_chat_participant": {
      "id": 1138406331,
      "is_bot": true,
      "first_name": "xxxxxxxxxbot",
      "username": "xxxxxxxxxbot"
    },
    "left_chat_member": {
      "id": 1138406331,
      "is_bot": true,
      "first_name": "xxxxxxxxxbot",
      "username": "xxxxxxxxxbot"
    }
  }
}
```

How can I transform something like `("date":`**`1583942557`**`)` to something like dd-MM-YYYThh:mm?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting Long to Date in Java returns 1970](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487460/converting-long-to-date-in-java-returns-1970)

Comment: Now that the previous comment is mentioning Java: are you using a programming language for that?

Answer (score 4):

Telegram creates timestamp of the message as a UNIX-time
(seconds since Jan 01 1970)

To convert it to 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' string you can use the following:

```
import datetime, time

data = json.load('json_file_with_telegram_message.json')

messageTime = data['message']['date'] # UNIX time
messageTime = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(messageTime) # datetime format
messageTime = messageTime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') # formatted datetime
    
TimeStamp = str(messageTime)
```

Enjoy!